# Chrome does not start on OSX after fresh install

Tags: macos, google-chrome

It does not matter if I install it via brew or the official google website.

When I start it, it returns an error message:

```
Path:                  /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
Identifier:            com.google.Chrome
Version:               78.0.3904.70 (3904.70)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Google Chrome [25447]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-10-29 21:12:38.185 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15 (19A602)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.0 (17P572)
Anonymous UUID:        624E795F-4392-2D73-55A9-FA070AADAF67

Sleep/Wake UUID:       BA0934C2-9072-4B7F-8D72-335B29B00F6C

Time Awake Since Boot: 41000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       780 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process:   exc handler [25447]

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.google.Chrome.framework     0x000000010d705f43 0x108af0000 + 79781699
1   com.google.Chrome.framework     0x0000000108af3b35 0x108af0000 + 15157
2   com.google.Chrome.framework     0x000000010b241a25 0x108af0000 + 41228837
3   com.google.Chrome.framework     0x000000010b24194e 0x108af0000 + 41228622
4   com.google.Chrome.framework     0x000000010daf8e19 0x108af0000 + 83922457
5   com.google.Chrome.framework     0x000000010b240f44 0x108af0000 + 41226052
6   com.google.Chrome.framework     0x0000000108af347b ChromeMain + 187
7   com.google.Chrome               0x0000000101ff5904 main + 372
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6ccf8405 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6cf015b4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6cf015b4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6cf015b4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6cf015b4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fda1e71a0b0  rbx: 0x00007fda1e60e1a0  rcx: 0x00000000000003e6  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000005  rsi: 0x00007ffeedc0b518  rbp: 0x00007ffeedc0b500  rsp: 0x00007ffeedc0b500
   r8: 0x0000000000000005   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000008
  r12: 0x00007ffeedc0b518  r13: 0x00007ffeedc0b998  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x00007ffeedc0ba60
  rip: 0x000000010d705f43  rfl: 0x0000000000000293  cr2: 0x000000010b3114c0

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     3


Binary Images:
       0x101ff4000 -        0x10201dfff +com.google.Chrome (78.0.3904.70 - 3904.70) <DDDD5CED-62D1-33FC-BB57-92084EDA4B95> /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
       0x1089ef000 -        0x108a7d93f  dyld (732.8) <42C11B81-6928-369F-B03E-D57355572700> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x108af0000 -        0x110ee0f17 +com.google.Chrome.framework (78.0.3904.70 - 3904.70) <A82589DF-0869-36A1-8720-5B06C9042155> /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/78.0.3904.70/Google Chrome Framework
    0x7fff3155b000 -     0x7fff31752ff2  com.apple.avfoundation (2.0 - 1722.27.4.5) <EC398B56-6AFF-3B51-837C-E2F9999097EA> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundation
    0x7fff31753000 -     0x7fff3181eff8  com.apple.audio.AVFAudio (1.0 - ???) <2ED23D7A-9635-3D52-BEFE-3044062B023A> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AVFAudio.framework/Versions/A/AVFAudio

[...]

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 288158
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=744.4M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=744.4M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=108.3M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=108.3M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CoreServices                        88K        1 
Dispatch continuations            24.0M        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                            71.6M       31 
MALLOC guard page                   16K        4 
PROTECTED_MEMORY                     4K        1 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        5 
Stack                             10.0M        5 
VM_ALLOCATE                         44K        2 
__DATA                            45.8M      354 
__DATA_CONST                        20K        1 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       351.1M        4 
__OBJC_RO                         31.8M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         1760K        1 
__TEXT                           393.3M      352 
__UNICODE                          564K        1 
mapped file                       54.2M       10 
shared memory                      640K       15 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.0G      792 

Model: MacBookPro15,1, BootROM 1037.0.78.0.0 (iBridge: 17.16.10572.0.0,0), 6 processors, 6-Core Intel Core i7, 2,6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 
Graphics: kHW_IntelUHDGraphics630Item, Intel UHD Graphics 630, spdisplays_builtin
Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonPro560XItem, Radeon Pro 560X, spdisplays_pcie_device, 4 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/ChannelA-DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR4, 2400 MHz, SK Hynix, -
Memory Module: BANK 2/ChannelB-DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR4, 2400 MHz, SK Hynix, -
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x7BF), wl0: Jul 24 2019 00:02:16 version 9.30.357.3.32.5.33 FWID 01-22b80374
Bluetooth: Version 7.0.0f8, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: Apple T2 Bus
USB Device: Touch Bar Backlight
USB Device: Touch Bar Display
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Headset
USB Device: Ambient Light Sensor
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Apple T2 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 47.3
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 47.3
```

At first it was not responding at all. After I put `sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome` once, now I get the error message. (Yes, I had a version of Chrome or Chromium up and running before the reinstall).

How can I fix this? And does someone have similar problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for being late!!

I was having the same issue and this helped:

In the Mac menu bar at the top of the screen, click Go.

Select Go to Folder.

Enter ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/ in the text field, then press Go.

Locate the folder called "Default" in the directory window that opens and rename it as "Backup default."

Try opening Google Chrome again. A new "Default" folder is automatically created as you start using the browser.

You solved it but i wanted to tell that only default folder need to be changed.

Comment: That is because you will have copied the path as it is, you have to check what exactly it is in your computer like in my computer it is  /Users/shubhsaras/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default. It will work I am perfectly sure. I have solved many such problems and its not a canary issue.You cannot delete the google folder as if you have more google apps like in my case I have 4, all their support data will be deleted. It is a issue with extensions external and local both, if you delete their data which is in default folder, it is solved.

Comment: Ok thank you for the explanation. I will try it next time!

Answer (score 5):

I actually had a similar issue where this answer gave me a strong clue about what was wrong. In my case, I did not have a 'Chrome' folder under ~/Library/Application Support/Google/ although I did have a 'Drive' folder, as I clearly installed Google Drive before installing Chrome.

I created the 'Chrome' folder manually and, as soon as I retried opening Chrome, it populated that folder with dozens of files and started successfully.

Apparently Google developers count on Chrome being the only Google product installed when it first launches?

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! But I cannot test or confirm this fix unfortunately because I do not have the issue anymore.

Comment: This was the solution for me as well. Also installed Drive first. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Owner of the directory was root, so this command helped me

`sudo chown %username%:staff ~/Library/Application Support/Google`

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! But I cannot test or confirm this fix unfortunately because I do not have the issue anymore.

Comment: This helped me. Though I needed to use the `-R` flag:

`sudo chown -R \`whoami\`:staff ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google`

Answer (score 1):

Add user to this folder ~/Library/Application Support/Google and set read and write,It solves my problem